# Como salvar dados simples locais do aplicativo?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, visual-studio-2017

Preciso salvar informações simples de configurações, só para quando o plicativo carregar ele recuperar algumas variáveis. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso sem recorrer ao SQL??

Ex: em programas windows eu costumo salvar configurações em XML, existe alguma coisa especifica para android e ios?

Obs: estou usando Xamarin

Comment: Cara, para o q vc quer, vc pode também trabalhar com banco de dados local no App usando um banco de dados com o Sqlite e mapeando as classe, bem prático e simples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O James Montemagno fez um plugin que talvez te ajude: [Settings Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) .